# Spring Oauth2 Get Current User Object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring 5 Oauth2. 
I can see current valid tokens.

```
Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientId("clientIdPassword");
    if (tokens != null) {
        for (OAuth2AccessToken token : tokens) {
            tokenValues.add(token.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Above code block shows me valid tokens whose client id is `clientIdPassword`, but I want to get only current logged user object. I tried `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`but it returns anonymous user. Is there a way to get the only current logged user object?

Comment: I am also stuck at same issue but no solution found yet. This issue is in case of Oauth2 + Spring security.

Answer (score 1):

In your Token Service, you can add the OAuth2Authentication Class as an argument

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/oauth/token/revokeById/{tokenId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void revokeToken(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String tokenId,OAuth2Authentication auth) {
```

Springboot will automatically map the logged-in user details to this object. Now, you can do the following to access the username

```
auth.getPrincipal().toString()
```

Comment: `OAuth2Authentication` returns null interestingly... But I do see the token from `tokenStore.findTokensByClientId("clientIdPassword");`.

Comment: @Chids Any idea on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229551/spring-oauth2-0-getting-user-roles-based-on-client-id

Comment: @eniss are you doing this logic in your authorization server and are you using jdbc token store?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, your code is the right way to get current login user object. 
If you want to find other ways refer here : http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: Please incorporate the content of your external link into your answer. Link-only answers are useless if the link it points to dies.